# Entity Framework Database Update: Foreign Key References Invalid Column (navigation property)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, navigation-properties, sql-update

This should be simple.

I have Clients and Projects:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}
```

All that is working fine. In my Projects table, I have the field: Client_ClientID storing the relationship.

Now I want to add a navigation property on Project, to Client:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    // navigation properties
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

When I run Update-Database, I get the error:

```
Foreign key 'FK_dbo.Projects_dbo.Clients_Client_ClientID' references invalid column 'Client_ClientID' in referencing table 'Projects'
```

The verbose SQL is showing as:

```
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.Projects.Client_ClientID', @newname = N'Client_ClientID1', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Projects] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Projects_dbo.Clients_Client_ClientID] FOREIGN KEY ([Client_ClientID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Clients] ([ClientID])
```

I'm not sure why it's trying to rename Client_ClientID to Client_ClientID1, before adding a constraint on it - seems odd?

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `ForeignKeyAttribute` to your `Project` class.

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Client")]
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Because I didn't start with that, it had used the name "Client_ClientID" as the FK field. I had to drop my tables and drop the __MigrationHistory, and then run Update-Database -Force to get it to recreate the schema as above. Seems to work now, plus it automatically has cascading delete (I can remove my manual application). Perfect!